# How to read file attributes using Master File Table data

Tags: c#, windows, file-attributes, ntfs-mft

In my project i want list out all files under a specific file path.Do to some user permission issue am using master file table to access all files.

Using this [thread](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CCS-LABS-C-Accessing-the-d317805c#content) I can able to read all files under a specific file location

This one will list the file name and parent FRN,is there any way to list the file attributes also????

I want to show these details also.

1. Created Date
2. Modified Data
3. File Size

USN_RECORD contains these details.
[image]

Comment: The USN_RECORD structure contains the file's attributes but not the other information you want.  But in any case that isn't an efficient way to solve your problem.  You have administrator access (otherwise you couldn't access the MFT) so just enable backup and restore privilege (which bypasses permission checks) and you'll be able to get the information you want the normal way.

Comment: USN_RECORD details screen shot is attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<FileDetails> EnumerateFiles(string szDriveLetter)
        {

            List<FileDetails> fdList = new List<FileDetails>();
            try
            {
                var usnRecord = default(USN_RECORD);
                var mft = default(MFT_ENUM_DATA);
                var dwRetBytes = 0;
                int cb;
                var dicFrnLookup = new Dictionary<long, FSNode>();
                bool bIsFile;

                // This shouldn't be called more than once.
                if (m_Buffer.ToInt32() != 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("invalid buffer");
                }

                // Assign buffer size
                m_BufferSize = 65536;
                //64KB

                // Allocate a buffer to use for reading records.
                m_Buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(m_BufferSize);

                // correct path
                szDriveLetter = szDriveLetter.TrimEnd('\\');

                // Open the volume handle 
                m_hCJ = OpenVolume(szDriveLetter);
                uint iny = NativeMethods.GetLastError();
                // Check if the volume handle is valid.
                if (m_hCJ == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Couldn't open handle to the volume.");
                }

                mft.StartFileReferenceNumber = 0;
                mft.LowUsn = 0;
                mft.HighUsn = long.MaxValue;

                do
                {
                    if (DeviceIoControl(m_hCJ, FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA, ref mft, Marshal.SizeOf(mft), m_Buffer, m_BufferSize, ref dwRetBytes, IntPtr.Zero))
                    {
                        cb = dwRetBytes;
                        // Pointer to the first record
                        IntPtr pUsnRecord = new IntPtr(m_Buffer.ToInt32() + 8);

                        while ((dwRetBytes > 8))
                        {
                            // Copy pointer to USN_RECORD structure.
                            usnRecord = (USN_RECORD)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pUsnRecord, usnRecord.GetType());

                            // The filename within the USN_RECORD.
                            string fileName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(new IntPtr(pUsnRecord.ToInt32() + usnRecord.FileNameOffset), usnRecord.FileNameLength / 2);

                            bIsFile = !usnRecord.FileAttribute.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory);
                            dicFrnLookup.Add(usnRecord.FileReferenceNumber, new FSNode(usnRecord.ParentFileReferenceNumber, fileName, bIsFile));

                            // Pointer to the next record in the buffer.
                            pUsnRecord = new IntPtr(pUsnRecord.ToInt32() + usnRecord.RecordLength);

                            dwRetBytes -= usnRecord.RecordLength;
                        }

                        // The first 8 bytes is always the start of the next USN.
                        mft.StartFileReferenceNumber = Marshal.ReadInt64(m_Buffer, 0);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit Do

                    }

                } while (!(cb <= 8));

                // Resolve all paths for Files
                foreach (FSNode oFSNode in dicFrnLookup.Values.Where(o => o.IsFile))
                {
                    FileDetails fd = new FileDetails();
                    string sFullPath = oFSNode.FileName;
                    FSNode oParentFSNode = oFSNode;

                    while (dicFrnLookup.TryGetValue(oParentFSNode.ParentFRN, out oParentFSNode))
                    {
                        sFullPath = string.Concat(oParentFSNode.FileName, "\\", sFullPath);
                    }
                    sFullPath = string.Concat(szDriveLetter, "\\", sFullPath);

                    //File Attribute details
                    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA data;                

                    if (NativeMethods.GetFileAttributesEx(@sFullPath, GET_FILEEX_INFO_LEVELS.GetFileExInfoStandard, out data))
                    {

                        fd.FileSize = Convert.ToDouble(data.fileSizeLow);
                    }

                    long highBits = data.creationTime.dwHighDateTime;
                    highBits = highBits << 32;

                    DateTime createdDate = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(highBits + (uint)data.creationTime.dwLowDateTime);
                    fd.CreatedDate = createdDate.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    fd.CreatedYear = createdDate.Year;
                    fd.FileType = data.filetype;

                    long highBitsModified = data.lastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime;
                    highBitsModified = highBitsModified << 32;
                    DateTime modifiedDate = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(highBitsModified + (uint)data.creationTime.dwLowDateTime);
                    fd.ModifiedYear = modifiedDate.Year;
                    fd.ModifiedDate = modifiedDate.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                    fd.FilePath = sFullPath;
                    fd.MachineName = SystemInformation.ComputerName;

                    List<string> names = sFullPath.Split('.').ToList();
                    fd.FileType = "." + names.LastOrDefault();                    

                    List<string> folders = sFullPath.Split('\\').ToList();
                    //fd.FileName = folders.LastOrDefault();
                    fd.FileName = oFSNode.FileName;
                    fdList.Add(fd);

                    yield return fd;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //// cleanup
                Cleanup();
            }
        }

public class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("KERNEL32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None)]
            public static extern bool GetFileAttributesEx(string path, GET_FILEEX_INFO_LEVELS level, out WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA data);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern uint GetLastError();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably be better off using something more high-level to enumerate the contents of a path (as suggested by @HarryJohnston), but if you're determined to go down the route you've chosen, then...

Using the FileReferenceNumber you got from your USN call, you can call [OpenFileByID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365432(v=vs.85).aspx) (specifying a 0 for the dwDesiredAccess parameter  - no read, no write), and you can then subsequently call [GetFileInformationByHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the details you need.

You don't need read or write permissions on the file to call GetFileInformationByHandle.  The file attributes you're getting from the USN call and/or the GetFileInformationByHandle call can be cast to a .Net System.IO.FileAttributes.

Comment: I *think* you would still need to have enabled backup and restore privilege, unless you have the appropriate access rights to either the file or its parent directory.  It would be a security hole if anyone could take a file ID and look up information about that file without having the right permissions to do so.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Probably right - not sure as the only context I've ever done MFT reading through is backup, restore and imaging (which is little more than indiscriminate backup).  In such a context, the OpenFileByID is supposedly much faster with dwDesiredAcces=0, in that no streams are constructed or returned - but again, my limited experience hasn't proved or disproved this assertion.  It seems very fast - but I have nothing to compare it to.