# Get file path from an unique file identifier in windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filesystems

I just read this post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866454/unique-file-identifier-in-windows) and wondered if it is possible to get a current file path from that ID.

So if a file gets moved can I get the new file path by searching for that ID?
Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about this topic.

Or is the ID only used to identify a file and can't be used to track the location ?

Thanks in advance.

// Added Code

```
public class WinAPI
{
    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr NtQueryInformationFile(IntPtr fileHandle, ref IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, IntPtr pInfoBlock, uint length, FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS fileInformation);

    public struct IO_STATUS_BLOCK
    {
        uint status;
        ulong information;
    }
    public struct _FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION
    {
        public ulong IndexNumber;
    }

    // Abbreviated, there are more values than shown
    public enum FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS
    {
        FileDirectoryInformation = 1,     // 1
        FileFullDirectoryInformation,     // 2
        FileBothDirectoryInformation,     // 3
        FileBasicInformation,         // 4
        FileStandardInformation,      // 5
        FileInternalInformation      // 6
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandle(IntPtr hFile, out BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenFileById(IntPtr hFile, FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR lpFileID, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, uint dwFlagas);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public uint dwSize;
        [FieldOffset(4)] public FILE_ID_TYPE type;
       // [FieldOffset(8)] public Guid guid;
        [FieldOffset(8)] public long FileReferenceNumber;
    }

    public enum FILE_ID_TYPE
    {
        FileIdType = 0,
        ObjectIdType = 1,
        ExtendedFileIdType = 2,
        MaximumFileIdType
    };

    public struct BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION
    {
        public uint FileAttributes;
        public FILETIME CreationTime;
        public FILETIME LastAccessTime;
        public FILETIME LastWriteTime;
        public uint VolumeSerialNumber;
        public uint FileSizeHigh;
        public uint FileSizeLow;
        public uint NumberOfLinks;
        public uint FileIndexHigh;
        public uint FileIndexLow;
    }
}

public class File_Handle
{

    public ulong Get_Index()
    {
        WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION objectFileInfo = new WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION();

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"D:\Test\Testfile.txt");
        FileStream fs = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        WinAPI.GetFileInformationByHandle(fs.Handle, out objectFileInfo);

        fs.Close();

        ulong fileIndex = ((ulong)objectFileInfo.FileIndexHigh << 32) + (ulong)objectFileInfo.FileIndexLow;

        return fileIndex;
    }

    public string Retrieve_File(ulong Index)
    {
        // WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION objectFileInfo = new WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION();
        // WinAPI.FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR Descriptor = new WinAPI.FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR { dwSize = sizeof(uint) + sizeof(WinAPI.FILE_ID_TYPE) + sizeof(long), type = WinAPI.FILE_ID_TYPE.FileIdType, FileReferenceNumber = (long)Index };
        WinAPI.FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR Descriptor = new WinAPI.FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR { dwSize = 100, type = WinAPI.FILE_ID_TYPE.FileIdType, FileReferenceNumber = (long)Index };

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"D:\Test\TestfileRef.txt");
        FileStream fs = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        //FileStream wf = new FileStream(WinAPI.OpenFileById(fs.Handle, Descriptor, 0, 4, 0x08000000), FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        FileStream wf = new FileStream(WinAPI.OpenFileById(fs.Handle, Descriptor, 0, 0, 0x08000000), FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION objectFileInfo = new WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION();
        WinAPI.GetFileInformationByHandle(wf.Handle, out objectFileInfo);
        fs.Close();

        wf.Close();

        return "Dummy";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of hardlinks, a file can have more than one path. The File Id is only guaranteed to be stable as long as somebody has a open handle on the file but they are always stable on NTFS in practice. Defragmentation can change the Id on FAT32.

You could try [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364953(v=vs.85).aspx) but results may vary based on the Windows version and file system.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but if I only know the file index, I dont have a handle. I also found this function, but I don't know how to create a hande from the file index.

Comment: Use OpenFileById.

Comment: Okay I tried to use the OpenFileById method but I am having some trouble here. I've created the Enum for the FILE_ID_TYPE and the struct FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR. But to use the function I need the descriptor, but I don't know where to get it so I tried to create it by myself. But I guess I messed up the dwSize because I get an "Access Violation Exception". Could you help me again with this ?

Comment: Yes you create/initialize it yourself. Did you set the size to 24? Is the struct large enough?

Comment: I just varied the size a bit but the problem still occures. Let me just repeat how I understood that method. "fFile" is a handle to a random file on the volume I have my target file on (the one I have the index from), The descriptor is used to determine what I want to do. In this case I have the FileIndex which is also stored in the descriptor.  I could also imagine that I messed up the "dwDesiredAccess", "dwSharedMode" or "dwFlagas". My current setup is 0,4, & 0x08000000.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Set flags to 0. If it crashes with access violation then the descriptor is too small/invalid or the pointer to it is wrong.

Comment: I included the code I reused and the function "Retrieve_File" I've written. Can you may check if its all garbage or only some mistakes ?

Comment: You need the GUID member and the struct needs to be exactly 24 bytes and so does dwSize.

Comment: But according to the WIN-API it is an union and can be the GUID or a LONG INTEGER (As described here in 2nd comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724343/get-file-info-from-ntfs-mft-reference-number).
Maybe the file index i pass to the retrieve function is wrong ?

Comment: Call GetFileInformationByHandle on a open handle so you know the id you get is valid. The union should be the correct size so you must include its largest member, the guid. Maybe ask a new question if you cannot figure this out.